# How to convert dynamic html after ajax call using html2pdf

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, pdf

I'm trying to set data dynamically in my html page , and after that I converted to pdf, and download it, this is my call url :

> createPDF.php?id=78

and this is my html part in createPDF.php :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function func(){
       jQuery.ajax({
        url:'******************/products/78',
        type:'GET',
        success:function(response)
        {

            $.each(response,function(index,product){
                jQuery("#pdfTitle").append( product.title );
                jQuery("#pdfDescription").append(product.description);
                jQuery("#pdfImage").append('<img class="img-responsive" src="' + product.meta_description + '" />');
                console.log('title='+product.title);
            });
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="func()">  
    <h1 style="color:red;">Description</h1>
    <p id="pdfDescription"></p>
    <p>Copyright © Test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

after that i have in the some file the php part to convert :

```
$content = ob_get_clean();
// convert to PDF
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');


$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');
$html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
$html2pdf->Output('Oumaya.pdf', 'D');
```

but i have always empty pdf , and this is what happen in console:

> createPDF.php?id=78:94 Resource interpreted as Document but
>   transferred with MIME type application/pdf

Comment: you can use the jspdf jquery plugin to convert the html into pdf file https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Comment: i'm try to use jspdf , but i have probleme with style and color :(

Comment: var doc = new jsPDF();

// I know the proper spelling is colour ;)
doc.setTextColor(100);
doc.text(20, 20, 'This is gray.');

Comment: i have my owen html , this is a relative solution !! , i want to convert hoal page with her style (color position , header ...)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `<?php ob_start(); ?>` at the beginning of the document in order for `ob_get_clean()` to work.